# Laravel: изменить данные в одной таблице на основании виденных данных в другую таблицу

Tags: php, laravel

Есть две таблицы: Задачи и Решения. Связь один к одному. Сначала на форме создаем задачу и ставим статус новая. Дальше это задача отображается в форме добавления решения. Пользователь выбирает задачу и нажимает добавить решение. В форме решения я добавила скрытое поле id задачи.
На форме решение тоже есть статус. Как поменять статус у задачи, на статус из решения
Модель задачи:

```
   public function statuses()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Status::class, 'status_id');

}
public function solution()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Solution');

}
```

}

Модель решения:

```
  public function task()
    {

        return $this->belongsTo(Task::class, 'task_id');

    }
    public function statuses()

    {

        return $this->belongsTo(Status::class, 'status_id');

    }
```

Контролеры(Solution)

```
   class CreateController extends Controller
{
    public function __invoke(Task $task, Solution $solution)
    {
        $statuses = Status::all();


       return view('serviceman.solution.create',compact('task', 'statuses','solution');

    }

}
class StoreController extends Controller
{
    public function __invoke(StoreRequest $request, Solution $solution)
    {
        $data = $request->validated();


        Solution::firstOrCreate($data);


        return redirect()->route('serviceman.solution.index');
    }

}

Request(Solution)
    class StoreRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'description' => 'required|string',
            'task_id' => 'required|integer|exists:rcs,id',
            'status_id' => 'required|integer|exists:statuses,id',


        ];
    }
}
```

И сама форма create

```
    @extends('serviceman.layouts.main')
@section('content')
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
        <div class="content-header">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row mb-2">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <h1 class="m-0">Создание решения</h1>
                    </div><!-- /.col -->
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
                            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{{route('serviceman.solution.index')}}">Главная</a></li>
                            <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Создание решения</li>
                        </ol>
                    </div><!-- /.col -->
                </div><!-- /.row -->
            </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.content-header -->

        <!-- Main content -->
        <section class="content">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Small boxes (Stat box) -->
                <div class="col-12">
                    <form action="{{route('serviceman.solution.store')}}"  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"  >
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="hidden" class="form-control w-25" name="task_id"
                                   value="{{$task->id}}">

                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group class = w-25">
                            <label>Статус задачи</label>
                            <select name="status_id" class="form-control">
                                @foreach($statuses as $status)
                                    <option value="{{$status->id}}"
                                        {{$status->id == old('status_id') ? ' selected' : ''}}
                                    >{{$status->status}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>


                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="summernote">
                                <textarea id="summernote" name="description">{{old('description')}}</textarea>
                                @error('description')
                                <div class="text-danger">Это поле необходимо заполненить</div>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                            <div class="for-group">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn  btn-secondary" value="Добавить"></input>
                            </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <!-- ./col -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->

    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
    </div>
@endsection
```

Данные в таблицу добавляет Solutions и task_id тоже проставляет правильно.

Answer (score 0):

**Вариант 1**
При создании/обновлении `Solution` через отношение можем получить модель `task` и там поменять статус. Например

```
....
$solution->task->update(
[
  'status' => $solution->status
]);
....
```

**Вариант 2** Observer (Данный варинат будет работать в пределах всего проекта, а не только данной формы) больше про обсерверы можете почитать [тут](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#observers)

В класе `Solution` переопределим метод `boot`

```
class Solution extends Model {

.........
  protected static function boot()
  {
    $closure = function(Solution $solution) {
      $solution->task->update(
        [
          'status' => $solution->status
        ]);
    };
    static::created($closure);
    self::updated($closure);
    parent::boot();
  }
.............

}
```

**UPD** У вас же отношение один к одному, а значит метод `tasks` и `solutions` всегда будут возвращать не более одной модели, поэтому их лучше перейменовать на `task` и `solution` соответственно.

**UPD 2**

```
class StoreController extends Controller
{
    public function __invoke(StoreRequest $request, Solution $solution)
    {
        $data = $request->validated();


        $solution =  Solution::firstOrCreate($data);
        $solution->task()->update(
        [
          'status' => $solution->status
        ]);


        return redirect()->route('serviceman.solution.index');
    }

}
```

Comment: Не получилась, выдает ошибку. Call to a member function update() on null. Никак не могу понять, как это сделать, уже кучу всего перепробовала и прочитала((

Comment: @КристинаИванова можете предоставить полный код метода сохранения?

Comment: Добавила код добавление в базу

Comment: @КристинаИванова  обновил ответ

Comment: @ Вадим Александру Спасибо  большое, все получилось добавила, как вы советовали к модели Решения функцию boot)